# Reconstructing a 2D shape from its projection in 1D

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry, differential-equations

I have a convex closed shape in 2 D space (on the x-y plane). I do not know what it looks like. I rotate this shape about approximately the center of its bounding box 64 times by 5.625 degrees (360/64). For each rotation I have the x-coordinates of the extreme points of the shape. In other words I know the left and right x extents of the shape for each rotation (assuming an orthographic projection). How do I obtain 64 points on the shape that do not contradict the x projections. 
Note that the 2D shape is rotating, but the coordinate axes are not rotating along with it. So if your object is a line, the x projection of each end if plotted will essentially be a sin/cos wave depending on its original orientation.

The higher the number of rotations, if I have the solution - the closer I will get to my actual shape.

In reality I do not know the exact point I am rotating the shape about, however any solution assuming I do know will still be helpful, as I don't mind the reconstruction being imperfect.

Comment: Is it a perspective projection or an orthogonal projection?

Comment: Do you rotate around a fixed point with known coordinates? And for each rotation do you get _two_ coordinates (left and right), or just the length?

Comment: If you rotate around a single axis, and only get the extreme coordinates, you will never reconstruct the shape completely: all you'll get is a bounding prism with edges parallel to the rotation axis. You have two options: consider the polygonal outline, or rotate with two angles.

Comment: Yves: he is observing a shape in a 2-dimensional space (and rotating around a point). With the stated restriction that the shape is convex and closed it is quite easy to prove that a point lies within the shape if and only if it lies within the 1-dimensional projection for all rotation angles in [0,2*PI] (no matter which point is the center of your rotation). To prove this, find any rotation which places the whole shape to the left (or to the right) of the point in question. Assuming that this is not possible for a point outside the shape will lead to a contradiction to the shape being convex.

Answer (score 3):

We used the straight-forward method to reconstruct.

Projection is a shade of the object.

You start with a bounding 2D box. For each projection you cut away from the 2D shape left and right parts that fall outside of the projection. So, the main function calculates intersection of two convex 2D shapes. You calculate these intersections for each projection.

We have several purple projections P1, P2, P3, P4 of the original green object:

[image]

Knowing position of a purple projection build two red rays coming from the end points of a projection and intersect them with the reconstructed object:

[image]

The red object was reconstructed using 4 projections. When compared to original green you can see that they are not the same. The more projections you have the less error you'll get in the final result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response - but x projection is on the x axis only. The x-axis is not rotating.

Comment: The 2D shape is rotating, but the coordinate axes are not rotating along with it. So if your object is a line, the x projection of each end if plotted will essentially be a sin/cos wave depending on its original orientation.

Comment: Great answer, trollish question and asker.

Comment: @gayathrichittiappa, it is not quite clear from the question. What information do you know about each projection? Is it just an angle of object rotation and `Xmin`, `Xmax` coordinates of the projection on the `X` axis? Nothing else at all? More specifically, do you know the coordinates of the point `(x,y)` around which the object rotates?

Comment: no nothing else at all.In my physical situation I do not know the coordinates around which the object rotates. But perhaps I could assume we are rotating it about the x and y defined by the centres of the 1st projection and the 17th projection, the other option is to assume that we are rotating it about the origin (0, 0) this is different from what is in my question. I have tried to find a solution where I don't need to know what the centre of rotation is.. but not sure this is the right approach

Comment: @gayathrichittiappa, I'm afraid, you do need to know the axis of rotation. In our case the center of the camera was more or less aligned with the axis of the motor that rotated the object. There were also calibration steps which effectively pre-calculated the equation of the rotation axis and determined the overall position of the coordinate system.

Comment: @gayathrichittiappa, having two opposite projections (rotated by angle `x` and `x+180`) you can calculate the `x` coordinate of the center of rotation. It is just an average of projection coordinates. Having 32 pairs of projections you can calculate it with less error by averaging results. I need to think further whether it is needed to know the `y` coordinate of the center of rotation and if it is possible to deduce it by projections.

Comment: @gayathrichittiappa, at a first glance it seems that you may choose any value for the `y` coordinate of the center of rotation (for example, zero), because all projections would remain exactly the same regardless of the actual `y` coordinate of the center of rotation. If you assume that `y` coordinate of the center of rotation is zero, it means that you move your coordinate system in such a way that zero of the `Y` axis coincides with the center of rotation. The final reconstructed object would be in that coordinate system. We need good illustrations. I'll continue tomorrow.